# Interfacing to an ipy exe using a socket

Tags: .net, sockets, ironpython, robotframework

Recently, I've been tasked with creating automation for a .NET software (Audio Precision APx500). My company's automation is based around Python and Robot Framework. Since Python has no inherent .NET support, my primary option is as follows: create a script using IronPython that interfaces with the APx500 API, compile this to an exe, and talk to that exe over a socket.

The client would be the python lib that I would import in RF. Methods in this lib would send a message over the socket to the server (the ipy exe), which would interpret the message and run a particular function of the APx500 API.

The problem lies in my lack of understanding of how to configure the socket server-side. I don't know how to properly receive and interpret messages sent from the client.

Say I do something like:

```
def startAP(self): 
    self.sock.send("open APx500")
```

How would the server interpret this to execute the correct task?

If there are better ways to do what I'm attempting, please, let me know.

Comment: Are you aware of the robotframework [remote library API](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface), and are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the robot framework [remote library API](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface) you don't have to worry about the lower level implementation. In your test you call  a keyword, and the remote API will send the request to the server which will execute a function and return the result.

You can build your server from scratch using iron python if you want, though it might be easier for you to use [nrobotremote](https://code.google.com/p/nrobotremote/). The wiki for that project has a page titled [How to write a keyword library](https://code.google.com/p/nrobotremote/wiki/HowToWriteKeywordLibrary) which shows how to use the library.

Comment: Say I write the lib in C#. What is the next step from there? I can't find anything in the nrobotremote wiki on how to load that lib.